# Как получить БД mysql на удалённом серверe к себе на локальный?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, putty, winscp

Столкнулся с таким моментом что у меня встала задача получить БД с удалённого сервера.
Подключался к нему с помощью winSCP, но как я понял достать БД через него я не смогу
Посоветовали DBeaver для этой задачи - скачал и не понял как подключиться к удалённому серверу
Также посоветовали навикат, но его я не тестил
**Суть вопроса:** как же мне всё таки правильно получить БД с удалённого сервера?
**Просьба:** пожалуйста опишите решение подробно по возможности

Comment: добавить пользователя, которому можно подключаться удалённо. Подключаться к БД по IP сервера и пользователя, которого вы создали. И в чём собственно у вас вопрос? Что вы делаете и что получается?

Comment: Впервые занимаюсь данной задачей поэтому попросил описать подробно)
У меня все данные подключения к удалённому серверу и я могу это сделать через putty или winSCP, но что делать после подключения я без понятия :/

Comment: Сделать бэкап, скопировать к себе и восстановить локально.

Comment: Akina, слова мне конечно знакомы, но реализация - нет)

Comment: Если putty у вас дает полноценный доступ к консоли сервера, то сделать бекап БД с помощью утилиты mysqldump (она устанавливается вместе с mysql, так что с очень большой вероятностью доступна из командной строки на сервере). После чего скачать через WinSCP полученный файл к себе и выполнить его с помощью утилиты mysql (так же входит в комплект установки сервера mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена
В случае с mysql я сделал следующее

```
mysql
```

С этого момента я ввожу sql запросы

```
show databases
```

посмотрели все имеющиеся БД и выявили для себя название нужной нам затем Ctrl+z(выход с режима mysql)

```
mysqldump -u user -pPassword --databases dbName > name.sql
```

Таким образом мы экспортируем бд на удалённый сервер в корневую папку и можем достать её через проводник WinSCP
P.S. есть нюансы между mysqldump к примеру в mysql 5.7 и mysql 8.0
P.S.S. при mysqldump будьте внимательны с направлением знака >. Если знак такой >, то мы экспортируем, если такой <, то это импорт файла бд с сервера в бд которая юзается

Comment: типо > в указанный файл, а < из указанного файла